# Show first view result, but show next result when the view's cache is cleared

Tags: caching, views

I'm trying to show a featured image on my homepage.
This image will be pulled in by a view that returns 1 result.
I then change the caching of the view to 1 day.

What I would like is for each time the cache resets the view to return the next row.

Day 1 - image 1 
Day 2 - image 2
etc..

I can add the sort criteria: 'Global: Random'. But then you have the chance that some images might be shown on consecutive days and that some are hardly ever shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have used some scheduling mechanism for node publish and unpublish instead of using views chache.

Some thing as schedule a node A to publish today and unpublish tomorrow, node B is unpublished today and will be published tomorrow, meanwhile the view will always pick the published nodes.

Node scheduling can be handled by [scheduler module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler).